# Problema em disposição de de produtos em Grid

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o site MK Gráfica onde na parte de categoria de produtos, especificamente em Banners e também em Promoções a disposição dos produtos em Grid está com problema, um ou outro produto aparece sozinho em certa linha, sendo que deveria continuar o padrão de 3 produtos. Isto pode ser visto [neste link](http://mkgrafica.com.br/banners).

E o problema especificamente [nesta imagem](https://postimg.org/image/ja48ogvxv/).

Tentei utilizar o css:

```
.row, [class*='col-'] {
    display: inline;
}
```

Mas não funcionou, e o estranho é que o problema aparece somente em algumas categorias.

Testei no Chrome versão 51.0.2704.103 e no Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então Wendell o problema é que você só tem colunas(`col`).

**Seu código hoje esta assim:**

```
...
<div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
<div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
<div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
<div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
<div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
<div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
...
```

**Para resolver seu problema, deveria estar assim:**

```
...
<div class="row>
     <div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
     <div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
     <div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row>
     <div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
     <div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
     <div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4"></div>
</div>
...
```

Uma solução alternativa é via css.
Adicione uma altura mínima assim:

```
.product-layout{min-height: 370px;}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver a utilizar o Bootstrap, não esqueça de utilizar assim para que seja responsivo:

`<div class="product-layout product-grid col-lg-4 col-sm-6"></div>`

Esta div é uma coluna com col-lg-4 o tamanho dela é de 4 colunas do bootstrap para dispositivos grandes, em md (notebooks) a mesma coisa, para dispositivos sm (tablets) e xs (celulares) esta coluna ocupará o espaco de 6 colunas, por padrão o bootstrap faz uso de 12 colunas. você pode adicionar quantas divs dessas você desejar dentro de uma div row (linha), quando o tamanho estourar a soma de 12 colunas elas automaticamente passarão para baixo criando outra camada. Porem se você diferenciar as camadas com as rows, o conteúdo pode não se organizar automaticamente.

Comment: <div class="product-layout product-grid col-md-4 col-xs-6"></div> Bootstrap usa *larguras mínimas* para seu grid, então não precisa declarar colunas da mesma largura. Você somente precisa declarar a menor até determinada resolução e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid